# Is there some precanned pop methods that already exist for angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just to pop up a window that has some static text and just one Ok button.

I know java\swing has a bunch of precanned classes that can just using one line of code that makes things very clean.
All of the angular pop ups I have seem like a lot code to implement for such simple piece of code. Angugular is supposed to make things easy to implement things there must be some easy one line methods that can be called.

Thank you very much for all of your help!!

Comment: `alert("Hello World")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to compromise when it comes to Angular because from my experience there's no pre-canned solution for popups that's ALSO powerful and customizable (talking about alert). What you should do is make a wrapper over a good popup library to suit your needs.

I think what you can do is to take ui-bootstrap's modal and Wrap all of the code needed for a popup in a factory.

Doing this will make it so that you can call the factory in any of your controllers and invoke a popup behaviour in ONE clean and easy to use line.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. You have two options: 1. use uib modal from the ui bootstrap package. It take few lines of code... 2. write your own directive that wraps solution 1 to one line of code :)

Comment: angular material has some nice ones as well

Comment: what is the best way to have a pop up with a dynamic text that can be changed from a button callback from a different controller

Comment: create a service and bind the text in the popup modal to the service's object. once the button clicked with different controller attached to it, update the service. as a result, the text in the popup will be changed.